# cygwin rsync slow when backing up 2 external HDDs

Tags: cygwin, rsync

I've written a shell script to backup my external HDDs through my laptop.  I've basically connected my external HDDs to the USB ports of the laptop and run the following command in the script to back up 1 HDD to another HDD.

```
 rsync -arvv "$flg" --log-file="$LOGFILE" "$srcdir" $BAKUP_DIR 2> "$ERRFILE"
 $ rsync --version
   rsync  version 3.0.9  protocol version 30
```

The flg is either --delete or spaces depending on how I want to back up the dir.  I believe this is slow for some reason I can't fathom.   I think it is transferring files unnecessarily when backing up.  I can see file parts being sent(and growing) when viewed through Explorer and wondering why it is so.

and the log file...

```
  grep -C 15 delta 2011-12-23-37_bk.log
  2011/12/23 14:28:34 [8712] total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=2133674141
  2011/12/23 14:28:35 [8712] sent 2133939896 bytes  received 772 bytes  1854794.15 bytes/sec
  2011/12/23 14:28:35 [8712] total size is 3901493999  speedup is 1.83
  2011/12/23 14:28:35 [5072] building file list
  2011/12/23 14:28:39 [5072] delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
```

Is this normal or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing exactly the same issue on a system were I had recently installed Cygwin: rsync was too slow. Using the --progress option I could see that rsync was transferring files at only around 2/3 MBytes/sec between an external USB 3.0 disk and the internal disk.

On a similar system, the same operation was working as expected (60/70 MBytes/sec).

After trying many things, I realized that "rsync --version" was 3.0.9 on the system were I had just installed Cygwin and 3.0.8 on the system were it was working fine. So it looked like 3.0.9 had broken something.

I copied the rsync.exe (v3.0.8) file from one system over the rsync.exe (v3.0.9) of the other system and now the files are transferred at the expected speed (60/70 MBytes/sec).

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem and I also solved it by installing rsync version 3.0.8. But instead if copying the .exe you can just re-execute cygwin's setup. In the package manager search for "rsync" the setup still contains an option to install 3.0.8, which means that you can easily downgrade from 3.0.9 to 3.0.8. From there on everything is back to normal and max. speed.

Answer (score 1):

I too was having this problem with rsync 3.0.9 on Cygwin64 (~3MB/s transfer).

Going "back" to 3.0.8 is not on option on Cygwin64 as it's not in the repo.

However I downloaded [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/) 3.1.0 and manually built it myself (just need gcc and make installed) and this improved a lot.

3.1.0 built myself manages ~35MB/s. Windows explorer copy was faster (about 50MB/s) but I'll take it!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with ~4MB/s rsync transfer rate. This speed is reported both by the Resource Monitor and with a -P to rsync. It had been tasked to copy backup files of ~200GB from one drive to another and for several years it used to work taking about 1.5 hours to copy them. Not real fast, but good enough for me. Something must have broken recently and no doubt due to some update to the Windows system since I hadn't updated Cygwin in a several years. The job started taking ~14 hours which is what made me look at it closer. I updated the x32 Cygwin I had been using to the latest (rsync version 3.1.0  protocol version 31) and installed the x64 version of Cygwin to see if it made any difference. Nope.

Thinking it might be one or the other of the hard drives that might be going bad, I made sure both were completely defragged and cleaned of any garbage. Then I replaced the "rsync -a" command I had been using with "cp -au" and measured the throughput. With cp it reads and writes at ~100MB/s which is what the hardware supports and it copies that ~200GB in about 30 minutes. So something in rsync isn't quite right.

My workaround is to abandon using rsync in favor of cp. It is way faster to just pre-delete the entire directory tree on the target and have cp copy a whole new one than to have rsync do its thing to keep the two directories in sync. There's probably an even better option, but this works for me.